# Cancel math with underbrace but ignore extra height

Tags: underbrace, cancel

I regularly use the `cancel` package to cancel out terms in mathematical expressions, but sometimes those terms contain underbraces. Take the following (contrived) example:

```latex
\[abc + \cancel{d \underbrace{(e - e)}_{0} f}\]
```

[image: Cancel with incorrect height]

Here, I cancel out the term $d(e - e)f$, and the underbrace emphasizes that it's the $(e - e)$ which makes the whole term 0. However, as you can see, the diagonal line extends far too low, and ideally it should ignore the extra height added by the underbrace. Using `\smash` and `\vphantom` as suggested in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140894/270231) works for simple cases, but sometimes that extra height can't be ignored entirely:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\underbracesmash}{mm}{\vphantom{#1} \smash{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    &= abc + \cancel{d \underbracesmash{(e - e)}{0} f} + ghi + jkl\\
    &= abc + ghi + jkl
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Cancel with correct height but also with underbrace intersecting a following line of math]

I *could* keep using `\smash` and `\vphantom` to make it work, but this seems unnecessarily repetitive. Even if I were to define more commands to reduce repetition, like I did above with `\underbracesmash`, this still seems like too much of a hack. Is there a simpler/more efficient way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does inverting \cancel and \underbrace command do the job ?

Comment: Then the underbrace would go around the entire term rather than just the part that I'm focusing on, and the cancel would go around only part of the term rather than the entire term

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Defining a command *is* useful.

Since `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` are candidates for being smashed in various occasions, we can catch two birds with one stone:

1. in many situations, the spacing around `\underbrace` and `\overbrace` parts is wrong, so we fix it;
2. we can manage situations in which they should be smashed, but keep the vertical space they occupy nonetheless.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cancel}

% better \ubrace{x}{y} than \underbrace{x}_{y}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ubrace}{mm}{\perhapssmash{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\obrace}{mm}{\perhapssmash{\overbrace{#1}^{#2}}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\perhapssmash}{m}{{#1}}
% smash and add
\NewDocumentCommand{\smashcancel}{m}{%
  \begingroup
  \RenewCommandCopy\perhapssmash\smash
  \cancel{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \vphantom{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
uvw &= abc + \smashcancel{d \ubrace{(e - e)}{0} f} + ghi + jkl \\
    &= abc + ghi + jkl \\
uvw &= abc + \smashcancel{d \obrace{(e - e)}{0} f} + ghi + jkl \\
    &= abc + ghi + jkl
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Always use `\ubrace` and `\obrace`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The `\vphantom{...}` code block that re-establishes the overall height and depth of the row must not be in the argument of `\cancel`.

Unless you have lots and lots of such terms in a document, I don't think it's worth your time to define shortcut macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cancel}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
uvw    &= abc 
       + \cancel{d \smash{\underbrace{(e - e)}_{0}} f}\vphantom{\underbrace{(e - e)}_{0}} 
       + ghi + jkl\\
       &= abc + ghi + jkl
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The third upvote of this answer raised my rep count to 500k. Many thanks!! :-)